# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maya.cmds'

Tags: python-3.x, maya, mel

I tried running a python script that imports maya.cmds and maya.mel as Maya python script in windows. (Maya - animation software by Autodesk)
I am getting errors while importing the modules. Can someone help me figure out this error?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLETk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please do not post screenshots with errors or code. Just post the code here.
Do you work with mayapy? And do you set your pythonpath appropriately?